# Google SQL instance stalled after restoring backup

Tags: google-cloud-sql

After restoring from backup my Google SQL instance is completely dead, I get a message "failed to create" and can't do anything, not even restart it! please help!

Answer (score 0):

In general this should not happen as we have automated processes to prevent instances from getting stuck like this; apologies that it appears that your instances has gotten stuck anyway. On the backend someone should have noticed this via an automated ticket and gone ahead and fixed whatever problem happened. If that hasn't happened, yet, please send an email to cloud-sql@google.com with your instance information (GCP project, instance ID, timing for when the issue happened) and we will look into this issue more.